# Stack Pseudocode Comparison

Tags: c, stack, pseudocode

I need to check two queues, (a and b) to see whether they are identical or not (same elements in same order). And at the end both queues need to look the same as the start. Only using push, pop, top and EmptyStack.

This is what I have but it doesn't make sense to me.

```
boolean ABSimilar(A,B){
    if (A.EmptyStack() != B.EmptyStack()) return false; // stacks same
    if (A.EmptyStack() && B.EmptyStack()) return true; // stacks are the same
    A_element = A.pop(); // grab elements
    B_element = B.pop();
    if A_element == null && B_element != null {
      A.push(A_element); // if !=, restore them and return false
      B.push(B_element);
      return false;
    }
    answer = ABASimilar(A, B); // compare
    A.push(A_element);  // restore
    B.push(B_element);
    return answer; // return answer
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? having the same elements in the same order?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Should've clarified.

Comment: This looks strange `if A_element == null && B_element != null` but besides that I think your answer is a bit unclear. Is it all elements in stack A that has to be identical to all elements in Stack B - in the same order?

Comment: Same elements in same order.

Comment: @SamSepiol OT but in that case I suggest you call your function **identical** instead of **similar**. Similar is confusing...

Comment: the java-tag has been removed as OP (in comment) told that OP wants C code

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is almost right.

The thing you are missing is a proper comparison of the element you are removing from A to the element you are removing from B.

You only check whether A_element is null and B_element is not, and return false in this case.

You should also return false if A_element is not null and B_element is null, or if they are both not null, but not equal to each other.

Only if they are equal to each other (either both null or both not null and equal) you should make the recursive call, which would compare the rest of the stacks.

```
boolean isABSimilar(A,B){
    if (A.isEmptyStack() != B.isEmptyStack()) 
        return false; // stacks same
    if (A.isEmptyStack() && B.isEmptyStack()) 
        return true; // stacks are the same
    A_element = A.pop(); // grab elements
    B_element = B.pop();
    if ((A_element == null && B_element != null) || (A_element != null && !A_element.equals(B_element))) {
        A.push(A_element); // if !=, restore them and return false
        B.push(B_element);
        return false;
    }
    answer = isABASimilar(A, B); // compare
    A.push(A_element);  // restore
    B.push(B_element);
    return answer; // return answer
}
```

Comment: So would I change this line:

   `if A_element == null && B_element != null {`

to this?

   `if (A_element == null && B_element != null) or (A_element !=null && B_element == null) {`

Honestly, I don't really know how to compare the element I'm removing from A to the element I'm removing from B. Would it just be like:

`if (A_element == B_element){`
`A.push(A_element);`
`B.push(B_element);`
 `return true;`

Comment: @SamSepiol `if (A_element == null && B_element != null) or (A_element != null && !A_element.equals(B_element) {...}` should be sufficient a condition for returning false. This would also cover the case when A_element != null and B_element == null. You don't need to add another condition that returns true. You only return true if the recursive call returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You have some minor problem with your code. Try like this:

```
boolean isABSimilar(A,B){
    if (A.isEmptyStack() && B.isEmptyStack()) return true; // stacks are the same

    if (A.isEmptyStack()) return false;  // stacks are different
    if (B.isEmptyStack()) return false;
    if (A.top() != B.top()) return false;

    A_element = A.pop(); // grab elements
    B_element = B.pop();

    answer = isABASimilar(A, B); // ckech remaining stack

    A.push(A_element);  // restore
    B.push(B_element);

    return answer; // return answer
}
```

Notice that a recursive method like the above is only to be used when you know that the size of the stacks are pretty small.

Also notice that **the above "code" can't compile as C code** for a number of reasons. Example:

1. `boolean isABSimilar(A,B)` is not a valid function prototype
2. `A_element` and `B_element` and `answer` are undefined

You need to fix that before compiling.

In C there isn't a built-in stack type so I assume that it's a custom type in your code. Something like:

```
struct Stack
{
    ... Member function pointers
    ... Member data
};
```

In that case your function should look like:

```
int isABSimilar(struct Stack A, struct Stack B){
    int answer;
    int A_element;  // I just assume that data type is int
    int B_element;  // but it can be other types (OP never told us)

    ... the code from above
```

Comment: Would I just declare at the top `A_element = Stack1() B_element = Stack2()`? What would I replace boolean with?

Comment: @SamSepiol I justed noticed that you have tagged with both C and java. My answer is for C. What are you looking for?

Comment: My bad. Its for C.